# No such column 'Description' on entity 'EntityDefinition'

Tags: soql, python, simple-salesforce

I'm trying to retrieve object descriptions with the following SQL query:

```
obj_info = pd.DataFrame(sf.query(
        "SELECT Label, Description FROM EntityDefinition WHERE IsCustomizable=True")[
                                              'records'])
```

Somehow he doesn't want to extract the description although according to [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm) it should be part of the EntityDefinition object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `toolingexecute` method from `simple_salesforce` for your use case.

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import pandas as pd

def queryWithToolingAPI():
    sf = Salesforce(instance_url='https://******--****.my.salesforce.com', session_id='00D0k0000009c**************PLzvO7pDsVFfuqwgAz')
    obj_info = pd.DataFrame(sf.toolingexecute("query/?q=SELECT+Label,Description+from+EntityDefinition+Where+IsCustomizable=True")['records'])
    print(obj_info)


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    queryWithToolingAPI()
```

As the `EntityDefinition`'s `Description` is only available via Tooling API.

From Docs:

> This field is available in Tooling API version 34.0 and later. Because this field represents a relationship, use only in subqueries.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That was indeed the issue. One question: Why are you passing the 'PyCharm' string to the function? It seems to have no use.

Comment: That leave it, I modified existing code snippet  which my IDE gives . and forgot to remove it. Will remove it now.

Comment: In the hope it may one day save someone 2 hours of frustration: The tooling API retrieves some additional objects, some of which don't have a "DataType" column for example.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are using the tooling API to execute the query.

If you are using regular SOAP or REST the description field may not be applicable

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I accepted Nagendra's answer as it is more detailed.

Comment: @ThaNoob Fair enough :)